# Makefile with multiple output rule not rebuilding nested dependency when run in parallel

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile with a rule that produces multiple outputs. To work around the issue of this rule often being run multiple times when run in parallel, I've used a dummy "timestamp file". I also have a rule that depends on the one of the outputs of this "multi-output" rule.

When all this is run from a clean state, it all works fine. However, if the source of the multi-output rule is updated, the other rule is not run, until Make is run again.

I've looked at the debug output, but haven't been able to make much headway. It almost seems like Make might be caching the old timestamp of the previous version of the multi-output file?

Hopefully the below demonstrates the problem adequately.

```
 $ cat Makefile
all: data.txt

multioutput.stamp: sourcefile.txt
        touch multioutput1.txt
        touch multioutput2.txt
        touch $@

FILES=multioutput1.txt multioutput2.txt

$(FILES): multioutput.stamp

data.txt: multioutput1.txt
        touch data.txt
 $ touch sourcefile.txt
 $ make
touch multioutput1.txt
touch multioutput2.txt
touch multioutput.stamp
touch data.txt
 $ touch sourcefile.txt  # update
 $ make  # data.txt is not updated!!
touch multioutput1.txt
touch multioutput2.txt
touch multioutput.stamp
 $ make  # except when it's run again??
touch data.txt
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what should I be doing instead?

Comment: With BSD `make` (`bmake`) works as expected, with GNU `make` doesn't (with or without parallel). It's very interesting.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html

Answer (score 2):

You are lying to *make*. Don't do that.

Once you have run the recipe of a rule, *make* checks to see if a file has actually been updated by the recipe. If it has not changed, you don't have to re-make any target that lists the file as a dependency.

Here you have given no recipe for `multioutput1.txt`, just a dependency line:

```
multioutput1.txt: multioutput.stamp
```

*Make* knows there is no way to update `multioutput1.txt`.

### Cheap fix

Force *make* to check the dependency by supplying an explicit recipe for `multioutput1.txt`.
Even an empty one will do:

```
${FILES}: multioutput.stamp ;
```

Yep, that's what the `;` signifies — the first line of the recipe follows on the same line.

### Better fix

The only way  of saying to make "this recipe creates two files" is with a pattern rule.
Then there is no need for a `multioutput.stamp`.

```
.PHONY: all
all: data.txt

%1.txt %2.txt:
    touch $*1.txt
    touch $*2.txt

data.txt: multioutput1.txt  multioutput2.txt
    touch data.txt
```

Here `$*` in the recipe expands to whatever the `%` matched in the dependency line.

Why have I made `data.txt` depend on both *multioutput* files?
Here I took the view that if either of `multioutput1` or `multioutput2` were missing, we should probably run the recipe to create both.
YMMV.

### Best Fix

YMMV but I don't like pattern rules.
They are too arbitrary for my tastes.

We observe that one of `multioutput1.txt` and `multioutput2.txt` will always be younger than the other.
They will never have the same timestamp assuming a modern filesystem.

```
.PHONY: all
all: data.txt

multioutput2.txt: start.stamp
    touch $@
    touch multioutput2.txt

multioutput1.txt: multioutput2.txt ;

data.txt: multioutput1.txt
    touch data.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. I've been reading https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html which mentions several of your solutions (and mine) with various drawbacks. Certainly your "better fix" is wrong, or at least a product of my own contrived example. In reality I have many "multioutput" files, and several "data" files that depend on different files produced by the multiple output rule

Comment: @LordAro First thing first: How is _Better Fix_ wrong? It covers all of the criticisms in _Multiple-Outputs.html_, even though that doc only notes pattern rules in passing. You can touch or delete any of the three files and _make_ will still do the right thing, parallel safe too.

Comment: It's not wrong, just doesn't help with my particular usecase - my actual files can't be used in a pattern rule - it's not actually data1.txt & data2.txt, it's otherwise unrelated names like foobar.txt, frobnicate.xml, etc, and there's about 10 of them